# What statistical blogs would you recommend?

Tags: references

What statistical research blogs would you recommend, and why?

Comment: I added the blogs in the question as answers to allow proper voting to find the most popular blogs.

Answer (score 25):

http://www.r-bloggers.com/ is an aggregated blog from lots of blogs that talk about statistics using R, and the [#rstats](http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23rstats) hashtag on twitter is also helpful. I write quite a bit about [statistics and R in genetics research](http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.com/search/label/R).

Comment: +1, also for the purpose of learning new statistical tricks (& generally keeping up w/ what's going on) w/ `R`, you should consider signing up for the [R-help (& possibly other) mailing lists](http://www.r-project.org/mail.html) as well. Your in-box will be spammed w/ 100 posts a day, but they can easily be ignored & you can just take in a quick note about topics that interest you w/o undue hassle. This will go part way towards covering the needs that r-bloggers serves.

Answer (score 22):

[Statistical Modeling, Causal Inference, and Social Science](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~cook/movabletype/mlm/) from Andrew Gelman is a good blog.

Comment: These were both listed in the original question...

Comment: By that reasoning another question which asks for the best blogs but lists other blogs in the starting question wouldn't be a duplicate of the question.
I think it makes sense to vote on all blogs to find out which are most popular including those already listed in the OP.

Answer (score 18):

[The Endeavour](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/) sometimes features statistics posts. Otherwise it is mostly around the interplay of computer science and math.

Answer (score 18):

In addition to those already mentioned, I like Rob Hyndman's blog:

http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/

I guess he's too modest to mention it himself! ;-)

Answer (score 12):

Cosma Shalizi's [blog](http://www.cscs.umich.edu/~crshalizi/weblog/), often talks about statistics, and is always interesting.

Comment: It doesn't have an RSS feed though :(

Comment: http://cscs.umich.edu/~crshalizi/weblog/index.rss

Comment: @Colin: The author of the blog would need to put `<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="http://cscs.umich.edu/~crshalizi/weblog/index.rss" />` in his the `<head>` section of the HTML document for Firefox to pick it up automatically :)

Answer (score 12):

[XI'AN'S OG](http://xianblog.wordpress.com/)

Comment: are there any sas related good blogs as well ?

Answer (score 9):

[Darren Wilkinson's research blog](http://darrenjw.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 6):

I like Dave Giles' blog [Econometrics Beat](http://davegiles.blogspot.com/) It has a time series focus, but lots of other interesting things as well. Here's a nice post on the [Pythagorean means.](http://davegiles.blogspot.com/2012/01/extracting-correct-meaning-from-data.html)

Answer (score 6):

[simplystatistics.org](http://simplystatistics.org/) is rather good. It is run by three biostatistics professors (Jeff Leek, Roger Peng, and Rafa Irizarry).

http://simplystatistics.org/

Answer (score 5):

Luckily now you don't have to spend too much effort finding good blogs.  [Stats Blogs](http://www.statsblogs.com/) is a relatively new aggregator which compiles a collection of blogs focused on statistics.  A lot of the blogs mentioned are aggregated there.

Answer (score 3):

http://blog.thegrandlocus.com/

This blog mixes basic concepts of statistics, everyday life and research. A must-read.

Answer (score 2):

[FlowingData](http://flowingdata.com/) is a good read, with an emphasis on data visualization

Answer (score 0):

[Statistical Ideas at statisticalideas@blogspot.com](http://statisticalideas.blogspot.com) for a mix of applied finance and theory.

Comment: Care to explain your recommendation or acknowledge any relationship to the author?