# Which machine learning blog do you recommend?

Tags: machine-learning, references

In the spirit of [What statistical blogs would you recommend?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114/what-statistical-blogs-would-you-recommend) I propose a collection of machine learning blogs worth reading.

Comment: I have already asked for making this question cw. I am happy to close it and reformulate the linked one to something like "Which data analysis blogs would you recommend" and altering the question text appropriately.

Comment: see a rather comprehensive list on [MetaOptimize Q+A -- Good Machine Learning Blogs](http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/3163/good-machine-learning-blogs)

Comment: I found this post in [quora](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-machine-learning-blogs). I am not sure if it is the same posted by @Pardis because I could not access that link.

Comment: thank you Pardis and Procastinator. Now what shall we do ? Deleting this question or copying content of the linked sites to that stats.SO may stand for itself ?

Comment: @steffen I do not think you have to take any of those actions. If the links were helpful, then you can keep the question. Also, it has two upvotes, someone may find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

[Larry A. Wasserman](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/)'s [Normal Deviate](http://normaldeviate.wordpress.com/)